# How to play snake in terminal?

Tags: games, gnome-terminal

Today I caught a teacher playing snake at his tty console. I know that he has Ubuntu. How does he made?

I tried to play myself in my treminal by typing `snake` and it told me:

```
The program 'snake' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install bsdgames
```

So, I installed `bsdgames` and then I started `snake`. But is not exactly what I expected. Is different from what I saw (a long, green snake). Any other idea?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for nSnake. Check http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/12/nsnake-play-classic-snake-game-in.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why don't you ask your teacher?!? Maybe you are interested in [`nsnake`](http://www.alexdantas.net/projects/nsnake/). To install it, run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nsnake
```

After is installed, you can start to play using:

```
nsnake
```

[image: nsnake]

<sup>(Source of the image: http://alexdantas.net/nsnake-screenshot.png)</sup>

Comment: I tried nsnake, but none of the motion keys work (h,j,k,l).  Dang it.